# Spring boot testing: User protected security controller on testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test, spring-security-test

Here you have my controller method:

```
@PreAuthorize("principal == '" + EspaiDocConstants.BO_COMPONENT_APP + "'")
public void ingestAudits() {
    // Do something
}
```

As you can see, it's protected using `@PreAuthorize("principal == '" + EspaiDocConstants.BO_COMPONENT_APP + "'")`

Here my test code:

```
@WithMockUser(username=EspaiDocConstants.BO_COMPONENT_APP)
@Test
public void test() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    this.controller.ingestAudits();
}
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting this exception message:

> DigestAuditsTest.test:91 » AccessDenied Access is denied

**EDIT**

In order to populate principal, I'm using a custom filter:

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET)
            .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
            .getBody().getSubject();

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null)
            );

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

So, `principal` is an `String` containing user.

Besides of that, I'm not able to change this code right now, and I'd like to know how to provide a `"String user"` to principal using `@WithMockUser`.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify only username, not whole principal object using "==".

> @PreAuthorize("principal.**username** == '" + EspaiDocConstants.BO_COMPONENT_APP +
>   "'")

Comment: Is JWTAuthorizationFilter called during debug?